# Understanding some NWBrowser I managed to get working

Tags: ios, swift

iOS 13, Swift 5

I managed to implement an `NWBrowser`, but I don't understand how this works.

```
var browser: NWBrowser!

func seek(typeOf: String) {
   let bonjourTCP = NWBrowser.Descriptor.bonjour(type: typeOf , domain: nil)
   let bonjourParms = NWParameters.init()
   browser = NWBrowser(for: bonjourTCP, using: bonjourParms)
   browser.browseResultsChangedHandler = { ( results, changes ) in
      for result in results {
         print("result ", result )
         if case .service(let service) = result.endpoint {
            print("bonjourA ",service.name)
         }
      }
   }

   browser.start(queue: DispatchQueue.main)
}
```

Now the result printed out looks like this...

```
result Result(nw: iPhone\0328._domino._tcp.local.@[lo0, en0], endpoint: iPhone 8._domino._tcplocal., interfaces: [lo0, en0], metadata: <none>)
```

How does this code match the above line? I just don't see it?

```
if case .service(let service) = result.endpoint {
     print("bonjourA ",service.name)
}
```

This prints out "iPhone 8"? But how does it find it with this code?

Comment: What exactly is confusing you here? You created a `NWBrowser` and asked it to find the nearby Bonjour services offered on the networks your iPhone is connected to. It found your `iPhone` on the network interfaces `lo0` (the loop back interface) and on `en0` (probably the WiFi interface)

Comment: Are you asking how this syntax works: `if case .service(let service) = `? I believe that`s called enum pattern matching.

Comment: I sm confused by the processing of the result. if case ,service(let service) = result.endpoint.. what does that say? Put another way, if I was just trying to figure this out... and I just don't reconize the syntax I guess? if case X

Comment: OK, but where goes .service come into the picture?

Comment: See the NWBrowser docs.

Comment: @Alexander can you provide a link to how you was able to decipher the statement?

Comment: @LanceSamaria I'm not sure what you mean exactly. There's not much to decipher. There's a few explicit references to well docmented types `NSBrowser.Descriptor`, `NWParameters`, `NSBrowser`, and the `browseResultsChangedHandler`). I just read the documentation, and connected it to what I already know about networking (`lo0` and `en0` are practically-universal names for the loopback and primary network intercaces, respectively).

Comment: @Alexander thanks for getting back to me. I literally started to dive into networking about 4-5 days. This is all new to me. The `lo0` and `en0` look strange. My debugger printed out `en2` and `awdl0`, I just googled those. I’ll read the docs on `browseResutsChangedHandler`. Thanks again 

Comment: @LanceSamaria Have a look at [`ifconfig`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ifconfig), [`man ifconfig`](https://ss64.com/osx/ifconfig.html)

Comment: Perfect, thanks for link!!!   